# Ionic Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hasownproperty, npm-scripts, ionic-cli

I'm using Ionic framework. I upgraded to a later version of the ionic cli and receive this error while running `ionic serve`.

How do I fix the issue to allow the project to run with `ionic serve` or `ionic build` again?

```
There was an error serving your Ionic application: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\lib\utils\npmScripts.js:16:31
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\***\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\***\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\***\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\***\node_modules\q\q.js:604:44
    at runSingle (C:\Users\***\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\***\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: try logic like this: if typeof VARIABLE !=="undefined" && VARIABLE.hasOwnProperty("field")

this will get you going

Comment: Please visit this link - I will provide steps below https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cannot-read-property-hasownproperty-of-undefined/68965/7?u=andrewoodleyjr

Comment: Step 1 - Create an empty package.json file {} in the root you can add stuff here later.

Comment: Step 2 - Move your index.html file to the root within www/ (this should not be in templates/)

Comment: Step 3 - Run the following commands `npm install; npm update;`

Comment: Step 4 - ionic serve - this should work now!